# How to iterate through two collections of the same length using foreach

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5, foreach

If we want to concat some properties of two collections assuming they have the same length, e.g :

**Collection 1 :**

```
$collection1 = Collection { ▼
  #items: array:2 [ ▼
    0 => Item { ▼
      +id: 1
      +first_name: 'first_name 1'
      +last_name: 'first_name 1'
      +nbr_hours: 9
    }
    1 => Item { ▼
      +id: 2
      +first_name: 'first_name 2'
      +last_name: 'first_name 2'
      +nbr_hours: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

**Collection 2 :**

```
$collection2 = Collection { ▼
  #items: array:2 [ ▼
    0 => Item { ▼
      +id: 1
      +first_name: 'first_name 1'
      +last_name: 'first_name 1'
      +nbr_hours: 10
    }
    1 => Item { ▼
      +id: 2
      +first_name: 'first_name 2'
      +last_name: 'first_name 2'
      +nbr_hours: 12
    }
  ]
}
```

How we could loop through them in same time and concat the `nbr_hours` attributes, for example so the output will be like :

```
$nested_collection = Collection { ▼
  #items: array:2 [ ▼
    0 => Item { ▼
      +id: 1
      +first_name: 'first_name 1'
      +last_name: 'first_name 1'
      +nbr_hours: 19
    }
    1 => Item { ▼
      +id: 2
      +first_name: 'first_name 2'
      +last_name: 'first_name 2'
      +nbr_hours: 22
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Once visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779075/merging-collections

Answer (score 1):

### First of all, requirements

A solution with using the foreach-loop to traverse through the collection(s) is wanted

### Approach with two collections with same items in same order

You can use the index of each element that you traverse to get the "partner element" from the other collection, in case the item count and sorting is the same for each collection.

```
foreach($collection1 as $index => $item){
    $hours = $item->nbr_hours . $collection2[$index]->nbr_hours;
}
```

---

### Approach regardless of sorting and item count

When your collection elements are not in the same order, or the collection item count is different, the query looks a bit more complex. In this case, you need to query elements where the id's are the same. To achieve that, we can change the collection indexes to the id's of the containing model. Now we can again use the index of one element to find the corresponding one in the other collection.

```
$collection2 = $collection2->keyBy('id'); //Change indexes to model ids 
$collection1 = $collection1->keyBy('id'); //For both collections
foreach($collection1 as $index => $item){
    $hours = $item->nbr_hours . $collection2->get($index)->nbr_hours;
}
```

Comment: What if the values are not on same order.

Comment: Then a more complex query may be created @SougataBose

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Collection methods, you could use this approach:

```
    $zip = $c1->zip($c2->toArray());
    $m = $zip->map(function($items, $key) {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($items as $k => $item) {
            $sum += $item['nbr_hours'];
        }
        $r = $items[$k];
        $r['nbr_hours'] = $sum;
        return $r;
    });
```

Basically, `zip` method will "merge" the arrays in the same key. Then, if you use the `map` method, you can iterate over the main keys. After that, you can deal with both arrays as items. So, you can make any kind of operations you need, and then return a new array as the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) method as:

```
$nested_collection  = $collection1->map(function ($item, $key) use($collection2) {
    $item->nbr_hours = $item->nbr_hours + $collection2->get($key)->nbr_hours;
    return $item;
});
```

**Note** - If the values are not on same order then you can use [`values`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-values) method.

> The values method returns a new collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers

Answer (score 1):

A small modification to @AmitGupta's answer. If the collection 2 is required to be matched by `$item->id`. Try the below answer. :)

```
$nested_collection = $collection1->map(function($item) use ($collection2) {
    $item->nbr_hours += $collection2->where('id', $item->id)->first()->nbr_hours;

    return $item;
});
```

Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a example with array what you can do to achieve this -

```
$c1 = [
['id' => 1, 'hrs' => 9],
['id' => 2, 'hrs' => 12],
];

$c2 = [
['id' => 1, 'hrs' => 10],
['id' => 2, 'hrs' => 11],
];

foreach($c1 as &$c) {
    // get the index for the id from the 2nd array
    $c2_index = array_search($c['id'], array_column($c2, 'id'));
    // Increment the value
    $c['hrs'] += $c2[$c2_index]['hrs'];
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/699103)